# Find if the parent's previous sibling's children (any of them) contain specific text

Tags: jquery, if-statement, parent, contains, children

I have this html:

```
<ul>
  <li id="JL20211" data-fruit-types="Apples, Oranges, Bananas">
    <div class="sm-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns" >
                <div  class="post">
                    This a post with some information about delicious fruit.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <div class="action-row">
                    <div class="tags">
                        <a class="tag">Apples</a>
                        <a class="tag">Orange</a>
                        <a class="tag">Bananas</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <a><span class="id">ID: Fruit 1</span></a>
                        <a class="button tiny share">Share</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </li>
 <li id="JL20211" data-fruit-types="Apples, Bananas, Pineapples">
    <div class="sm-content">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns" >
                <div  class="post">
                    This another post with some information about delicious fruit.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="large-12 columns">
                <div class="action-row">
                    <div class="tags">
                        <a class="tag">Apples</a>
                        <a class="tag">Bananas</a>
                        <a class="tag">Pineapples</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <a><span class="id">ID: Fruit 2</span></a>
                        <a class="button tiny share">Share</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

And I currently have this jQuery ([jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/fletchling/rahx6/15/)):

```
$('.share').click(function(){
    var postText = $(this).closest('.row').prev('.row').find('.post').html();       
    if($(this).parent().prev().find('.blerp')){
        console.log('This version should not show up!');
    }else{
        console.log(postText);
    }
});
```

Ultimately, I am trying to find out if `.share` 's `parent`'s `sibling`'s `children` `contain` text.  So basically, I want to know if the `.share` button's closest  `<a class="tag">` contains a specific word like, "Orange".  In the fiddle you can see that I can't even manage to get it to log the correct words when trying to find if the parent's previous sibling has a child with a specific class. The class of blerp doesn't exist anywhere in my code and yet it continues to log the content as if it was.

I have tried multiple jQuery tags such as:

```
$(this).parent().siblings('.tags').find('.tag')
$(this).parent().siblings('.tags').children('.tag')
$(this).parents('.action-row').find('.tags > .tag')
$(this).closest('.action-row').find('.tags > .tag')
$(this).closest('.right').prev('.tags).find('.tag')
```

and that's just a few, I can list more variations if necessary.  I started trying to figure out how to get the `:contains` to work with this long mess and then realized I had problems way before I got there.  Any help out there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can also make your function a bit more performant by attaching it only once, instead of to each element with the `share` class.

Given your HTML, the following will work to determine whether or not the text is there:

```
$('body').on('click', '.share', function() {
    var text = 'Orange';
    var contains_text = $(this).closest('.action-row').find('.tag:contains(' + text + ')').length > 0;
    if (contains_text) {
        console.log('Found "' + text + '"');
    }
});
```

Rather than attaching to body, you should probably give your `ul` element an ID and attach there, like I have done in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rahx6/17/).

Side note: You have a duplicate ID `JL20211` on your `li` elements.

Comment: Oh geez! So close but so far. Thank you so much. And good tip on attaching to the ul. That honestly would never have occurred to me otherwise.